# When are dupes not dupes?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Asking similar questions - process?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/asking-similar-questions-process)

It's a pretty simple question actually, should duplicate questions be allowed if the original question did not get an accepted answer? Should I bw allowed to ask the same question every day until I get a satisfactory response?

Comment: What a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8299/asking-similar-questions-process http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/when-is-a-duplicate-question-not-a-duplicate http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8910/asking-a-similar-but-not-the-same-question

Comment: Yeah, that was too ironic *not* to happen.

Comment: This is another instance where combining questions would have been warranted.

Comment: Yeah, I had to rush off to take the kid to the bus stop. Sorry for the dupe.

Comment: For what it is worth, this is the question that prompted me to ask the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1346796/getting-row-from-gridview-in-dev-express and what happened there is the exact opposite of the answers in every one of those duplicates of my question here.

Comment: One of things that's important is that the question that I answered (as I found out) has an answer that is potentially worthy of a 'Reversal' badge. So, what happens if it gets migrated? Does the author of the answer lose his ability to get that badge because he answered a duplicate?

Comment: I think this is worthy of discussion. It can't be the only time that it has happened. So my question now is: Should I open a new MSO question specifically about this one situation? Or would that just get closed as a dupe?

Comment: Poor Alanis Morisette

Comment: When they're ajar?

Answer (score 3):

> should duplicate questions be allowed if the original question did not get an accepted answer?

Yes. The potential for you to word your question in a better way is worth having the duplicate in the system.

> Should I bw allowed to ask the same question every day until I get a satisfactory response?

God no. Edit it daily until a particular phrasing gets you where you need to be.

Comment: +1, although I don't think it's so much a matter of different phrasing as it is additional information that you can provide as you work through the problem on your own.

Comment: In my case, I do not have a comp-sci degree and there are times where my vocabulary fails me as a result. I have found that different phrasings attract different audiences, both in the question title and in the body. It sometimes takes a few tries in order to strike the right mix of vocab and code to get a solid response.

Comment: So which answer is right? Should I duplicate my question because "The potential for you to word your question in a better way is worth having the duplicate in the system." or "God no. Edit it daily until a particular phrasing gets you where you need to be."

Comment: @EBGreen: Duplicate someone else's question if you think you can ask it better. Once you ask your question, edit it. Don't ask it again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just bump the original question by making an edit to its body. But do so only after enough time has passed, so as not to spam the front page with your edits.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt ask the same question everyday.  Instead, you should attempt to make your original question 'better' or at least more attractive through edits.  This will put bump the question to the main page again. If you didnt get answers to the first question, chances are a dupe will not get answers again.